# Running python on mac

Tags: python

I have to learn python for a school project and I need a way I can code it and run it on my computer. Is there a way I can run python on safari via an MAMP web server. I have looked everywhere and can't grasp a grip on how I can run it as a page on my server. Thank you for your time. and thanks for the dislikes

Comment: why don't you download python directly?

Comment: I have tried I have IDLE and python launcher but they don't work. @JulienBernu MAMP has built in python but i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://www.pythonanywhere.com if you don't want to install Python on your computer for any reason.

Comment: thanks ill try that.

Answer (score 0):

An amazing programing website is c9.io. It has access to nearly all the mainstream programming languages. Just check it out and you can make an account for free.

Go there here: c9.io